# How to grep http request and response for specific MSISDN in logs

Tags: shell, parsing, grep, solaris-10

I want to grep http request and response from log file and i use following criteria

- First i grep msisdn in logs

  > less service.log

  Check pattern  /msisdn  like 1234567
  Above commands give me place where i received request in logs
- Then get the id of that http request from logs
- on base of that id i get response of the request

Above steps done on one file as all available in one file.

Now i want to automate above steps, i use following commands

sample request and response is following which present in one file

```
ID: 10814276
Address: http://1.1.1.1:80/myws?wsdl
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Headers: {Accept=[application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*],                      Cache-Control=[no-cache], Content-Length=[1363], content-type=[text/xml; charset=UTF-8],     Host=[x.x.x.x:80], P
ragma=[no-cache], SOAPAction=["Cancel"], User-Agent=[Axis/1.4], X-Forwarded-For=[1.1.1.1]}
Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<Cancel ><msisdn>12345678</msisdn><transactionId>955316475</transactionId>    
</Cancel>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Following is response

```
ID: 10814276
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {nmrMessage=[Message []]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">    <soap:Body><CancelResponse><responseCode>4020100</responseCode><description>Exception:     {java.lang.LinkageError: com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/ver1_1/Fault1_1Impl}</description>    <status>1</status><actionCode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:nil="true"/><inactivationDate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:nil="true"/></CancelResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Huh? msisdn isn't in your input or output, so how can I grep for it?

Comment: it was there but some formatting make that hide, sorry

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please put the names of the files immediately above the sample content. Then change your description so you say what you are looking for in which file. Also say what parameters you expect to supply to any script that anyone writes for you.

Comment: Above outputs are in one log file named service.log and only one parameter will be provided and that will be msisdn. so i want that i provide msisdn to script and it will return httprequest and httpresponse as visible above.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could provide some more sample input, i.e. something that contains more than one ID.

Comment: It is not clear. Let's say both pieces belong to the same file. Then, what is the pattern to look for? And what's the output you need from that given sample input?

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan Where is the `payload` information coming from shown in your response?

Comment: This sounds more like a sed, awk, or perl job. "grep" on its own will be very difficult to use. It may also require two or more passes through the request log to extract all relevant request IDs. And then a pass through the response log.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lookup_id() {
    local id
    id="$1"
    grep -e ^ID: -e '<msisdn>' service.log | awk '
    BEGIN { RS="ID: "; FS="\n" } 
    { 
        if ($2) { 
           sub(/.*<msisdn>*/, "", $2)
           sub(/<\/msisdn>.*/, "", $2)
           print $2 " " $1 
        } 
    }' > msisdn_to_id
    lookup=$(grep $id msisdn_to_id | awk '{ print $2 }')
    awk 'BEGIN { RS="ID: "; ORS "\n" } 
    $1 == '$lookup' && !match($2, /^Address/)  { 
        print "ID: " $0 
    }' service.log
    rm msisdn_to_id
}

lookup_id 12345678
```

I've tried to keep this POSIX-compliant to run on Solaris, but it was written on Ubuntu and some work may be needed (particularly on the Awk parts)